# How to set up more than one activity in android development?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface

i'm a ios developer trying to approach the android world. I've set up my first activity, but i'm a really bit confused.
To develop the user inteterface of an app, i have to develop every single view as a separated xml file? There's nothing analog to the Xcode Storyboard?
Can someone give me a simple idea of what i'm gonna do in order to develop a simple app made of more than one view, and some button leading to different views?

Comment: you should start with the tutorials, maybe a book. http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: i'm trying, but i find difficult to get the idea beneath the whole thing. The organization of the interface for example, as i asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand what a big difference developing on iOS is to Android so here's the basics:

- In Android, you have activities, which is just a fancy way of saying pages or views. You have an XML layout file and a Java file which performs functionality tasks.
- In order to switch between activities you need to create intents.

Here's a sample I've just made:

XML File 1

```
<LinearLayout>
//Layout stuff in here
</LinearLayout>
```

Java File 1

```
public void nextActivity(View view)
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Java File 2

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setupActionBar();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
}
```

If you need further help, follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may start with a good training tutorial here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html.

Later on you can see the views "layout" here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html.

The activity_main.xml contains the layout that includes your views in this layout. The Eclipse ADT Plugin and Android SDK provide a similar editor with Storyboard to drug and drop buttons, textfields etc.